# Package error IOS_13 on Windows platform only

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I just updated the project to 5.0 from 5.0EA. While in editor everything runs fine but I tried to package it for some testing, and I’m getting the following error, even tho in Project Settings I only have checked Windows as platform. I wasn’t getting this error before, is there something I’m missing?

`LogClass: Warning: In asset ‘None’, there is an enum property of type ‘EIOSVersion’ with an invalid value of ‘IOS_13’`

`LogObj: Error: LoadConfig (/Script/IOSRuntimeSettings.Default__IOSRuntimeSettings): import failed for MinimumiOSVersion in: IOS_13`

Comment: Well, you _are_  trying to import iOS settings. And yo probably have a very outdated file somewhere telling which iOS settings are allowed.

Comment: Can you be more specific where I can find those settings/files? I really don't care about any other platform than Windows, and I never did, it must have been something added by default in EA and now changed with official launch (maybe it used to support IOS 13 and now it is min 14, I don't know). I did saw something in Project Settings where I could chose IOS version and it had only 14 and 15, even tho I don't use it I looked around to maybe find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled UE5 and then removed all of it's files from AppData, reinstalled it and the problem is gone. I don't know why it was trying to use IOS too even tho it wasn't checked but at least that was the solution for me. Just uninstalling are reinstalling wasn't enough.